# Gerar sequencia de datas dentro de input de forma automática

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como posso gerar uma sequencia de datas e colocar cada data dentro de inputs( OS INPUTS JÁ EXISTEM DENTRO DE UM FORM) a partir da data inicial e final de forma automática?

Coloco a data inicial e final e o *script* gera o intervalo de datas em inputs que já existem. Não é p gerar os input's. E sim colocar as datas geradas dentro deles. Um `input` para cada data.

SCRIPT TESTE QUE GERA O INTERVALO DE DATAS

```
 var dt= new Date();
 var ndt = new Date(1850,01,27);      
 var diassem = ndt.getDay();     
 var mes=ndt.getMonth();

 var meses = new Array("Janeiro","Fevereiro","março");
 var dias = new Array("Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sabado");
    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
    {      
      var dia=ndt.getDate()+i;
      document.write(dia+"________");
      *****AQUI EU CONSIGO IMPRIMIR, MAS N CONSIGO PEGAR CADA DATA GERADA E COLOCAR NOS INPUTS DE ACORDO COM O ID DE CADA UM ( dti0, dti1, dti2....)****

    };
```

FORMULARIO TESTE ONDE VOU MANDAR SALVAR NO BANCO DE DADOS

```
<form method="POST" action="teste.php">
 <input type="text"  name="dti0" id="dti0" autocomplete="off"/><br>
 <input type="text"  name="dti1" id="dti1" autocomplete="off"/><br>
 <input type="text"  name="dti2" id="dti2" autocomplete="off"/><br>
 <input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti3" autocomplete="off"/><br>   
</form>
```

Tá meio que rascunho meu código. Nele eu consigo gerar a sequência de datas, mas ainda não sei como colocar cada data dentro de um `input`

Comment: você pode usar um for para gerar um loop da data inicial até a data final fazendo uma verificação se a data corresponde ao intervalo desejado dai você imprime o input.

Comment: Obrigado por responder. Mas a parte de escrever o valor no input é q não consigo. Conseguir gerar a sequencia e imprimir com o document.write, mas n consigo atribuir cada data a um inpu diferente. Pd me orientar?

Comment: pode postar o código que você gerou?

Comment: Tá meio q rascuno. To usando só a var ano como teste por enq                                                                                        var dt= new Date();

     var ndt = new Date(1850,01,27);  
    
     var diassem = ndt.getDay();
     
     var mes=ndt.getMonth();
    
     var meses = new Array("Janeiro","Fevereiro","março");
     var dias = new Array("Domingo","Segunda","Terça","Quarta","Quinta","Sexta","Sabado");



    for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) 
    {      
      var dia=ndt.getDate()+i;
      document.write(dia+"________");
           
    };

Comment: tente mudar esse trecho document.write('<input type="text" value="'+dia+'" name="dia">')

Comment: Olá Alisson. Eu tentei postar o código mas sou nova aqui. Então eu acrescentei o código que fiz na pergunta. Espero q consiga compreender.

Comment: Pois é, mas n consigo. N sei como. Já tentei usar o document InnerHTMlId, p encontrar o id de cada input e colocar o valor gerado. Mas n consegui. Esqueci de mencionar, mas os inputs devem ser preenchidos. Pq fazem parte de uma tabela e la eu salvo no BD>

Comment: eu entendi o que você precisa e dentro do document.write você consegue imprimir html.

Comment: se você quiser imprimir dentro de uma div todos os inputs troque o document.write por $("#divPrincipal").append("<input type="text" value="'+dia+'" name="dia[]">");

Comment: Eu qr q se seja colocado cada data gerada, dentro de um input diferente. Os inputs já existem, pois fazem parte de um formulario que deve ser salvo no Banco de Dados. Me desculpe pela complicação;

Comment: Troquei o id da DIV principal pelo id de um dos input's. Tentei adaptar seu código apagando parte dele. A lógica é essa, mas n sei como fazer. Qual o jeito certo de pegar o valor e setar no input?    $("#dti").append(value=dia);

Comment: Coloque o HTML do formulário com os inputs que vc quer inserir as datas.

Comment: É só um exemplo pq o form é maior.           <form method="POST" action="teste.php">
     <input type="text"  name="dti0" id="dti0" autocomplete="off"/><br>
     <input type="text"  name="dti1" id="dti1" autocomplete="off"/><br>
     <input type="text"  name="dti2" id="dti2" autocomplete="off"/><br>
     <input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti3" autocomplete="off"/><br>   
  </form>              .P cada input desse, quero colocar uma data gerada pelo array.

Comment: Mas qual seria o formato da data? Seu `for` diz `<= 10;` mas só tem 4 inputs, vai gerar erro.

Comment: Tem razão. Mas eu fiz como teste p código n ficar muito grande, como exemplo msm. Pd adotar o for só com 4 msm. E o formato n importa agora. Minha dificudade tá em colocar os valores gerados dentro de cada input. Vc pd me ajudar?

Comment: Muito obrigada pela atenção. Ajudou demais msm. Obrigada. Leo CAraciolo

Comment: Ok, vou colocar como resposta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método  [toLocaleDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) retorna uma string com a representação de parte da data baseando-se no idioma.

```js
var start = new Date("1850,01,27");

var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

document.getElementById("dti0").value =start.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR',options);

for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
{
   //estabelece um intervalo entre as datas    
   var newDate = start.setDate(start.getDate() + 3);
   start = new Date(newDate);
   //coloca as datas nos inputs
   document.getElementById("dti"+i).value =start.toLocaleDateString('pt-BR', options);
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  name="dti0" id="dti0" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti1" id="dti1" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti2" id="dti2" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti3" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti4" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti5" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti6" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti7" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti8" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti9" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
<input type="text"  name="dti3" id="dti10" autocomplete="off" size="51"/><br>
```

Comment: Obrigada, mas já deu certo.